# Me podrian decir por que se genera esto

Tags: c#, visual-studio

cuando le doy click al boton de insertar los datos se agregan repetidamente la cantidad de veces segun la cantidad de asignatura.

[image: lo que pide el programa]

[image: se utiliza ciclos anidados uno para cantidad de estudiantes y el otro para la cantidad de asignaturas por cada estudiante]

[image: ...]
[image: ...]
[image: solo le doy click una ves y repite el ciclo hasta que se cumplan, los 2 el de estudiantes y el de cantidad de materias]

Comment: Hola Freddy, bienvenido a la comunidad. Es más fácil leer tu código y poder apoyarte si lo agregas como texto, así sería más factible poder replicarlo para entender que puede estar pasando.

Comment: Quizá si te enfocas en una sola cosa a la vez sea más fácil. También declara las variables cuando las vayas a usar, así puedes seguir mejor la lógica del programa. De hecho, siempre es preferible que las variables tengan el menor alcance posible.